# Pandas の DataFrame にビットを振りたい

Tags: python, pandas

以下に示すようなDataFrameとlistがあります。

DataFrameのうち、listに含まれる要素と一致する行に対してビットを振りたいです。
例えば以下のようにするとビットを振ることができますが、for文を使うのでは処理が遅すぎます。
同様の処理をより高速に実装するにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

**試したコード:**

```
for i, j in lst:
    df.loc[(df["target"] == i) & (df["sepal_length"] == j), "bit"] = 1
```

**対象のDataFrameとlist**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "target": [
            "setosa",
            "setosa",
            "setosa",
            "versicolor",
            "versicolor",
            "versicolor",
            "virginica",
            "virginica",
            "virginica",
        ],
        "sepal_length": [5.4, 5.3, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.1, 5.6, 5.3],
        "sepal_width": [3.1, 3.4, 3.6, 3.1, 3.3, 3.8, 3.3, 3.4, 3.0],
    }
)
lst = [
    ["setosa", 5.4],
    ["versicolor", 5.5],
    ["versicolor", 5.1],
    ["virginica", 5.1],
    ["virginica", 5.3],
    ["virginica", 5.2],
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df['bit'] = df[['target', 'sepal_length']].apply(list, axis=1).isin(lst).astype(int)
print(df)

#
       target  sepal_length  sepal_width  bit
0      setosa           5.4          3.1    1
1      setosa           5.3          3.4    0
2      setosa           5.2          3.6    0
3  versicolor           5.3          3.1    0
4  versicolor           5.4          3.3    0
5  versicolor           5.5          3.8    1
6   virginica           5.1          3.3    1
7   virginica           5.6          3.4    0
8   virginica           5.3          3.0    1
```